# Insert node at a certain position in a linked list C++

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, position, nodes

I'm trying to insert a node at a certain position. In my code, the numbers with position 1 is only being inserted (basically at the beginning of the linked list) and it is not inserting any data with position 2. Is there something wrong with temp2? When I ran the program it is not pointing to anything I think.

I know how much you guys hate homework problems being asked here but I just don't know what is wrong with my program. I'm just a beginner at this and my teacher didn't explain linked list well.

The code is below.

-The output that I'm getting is 8 7

-I would want it to read 8 6 7 5 where 6 and 5 are inserted at position 2

```
/*
Insert node at a given positon in a linked list.
First element in the linked list is at position 0
*/

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node
{
   int data;
   struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *head;

void Insert(int data, int n)
{
   Node* temp1 = new Node();
   temp1->data = data;
   temp1->next = NULL;
   if (n == 1){
    temp1->next = head;
    head = temp1;
    return;
   }
   Node* temp2 = new Node();
   for (int i = 0; i < n-2; i++){// i feel like it doesn't even go through this loop
    temp2 = temp2->next;
   }
   temp1->next = temp2->next;
   temp2->next = temp2;
}
void print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    head = NULL; //empty linked list
    Insert(7,1); //List: 7     
    Insert(5,2); //List: 7,5   
    Insert(8,1); //List: 8,7,5 
    Insert(6,2); //List: 8,6,7,5      
    print();
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: In the `Insert` function, first you need to go to the node where you want to insert.,.. so you need `Node * temp2 = head;` instead of `Node * temp2 = new Node();`. And also, `head` at this time may be NULL.. so need to check for that.

Answer (score 8):

Just have something like this where you traverse till the given position and then insert:

```
void addNodeAtPos(int data, int pos)
{
  Node* prev = new Node();
  Node* curr = new Node();
  Node* newNode = new Node();
  newNode->data = data;

  int tempPos = 0;   // Traverses through the list

  curr = head;      // Initialize current to head;
  if(head != NULL)
  {
    while(curr->next != NULL && tempPos != pos)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        tempPos++;
    }
    if(pos==0)
    {
       cout << "Adding at Head! " << endl;
       // Call function to addNode from head;
    }
    else if(curr->next == NULL && pos == tempPos+1)
    {
      cout << "Adding at Tail! " << endl;
      // Call function to addNode at tail;
    }
    else if(pos > tempPos+1)
      cout << " Position is out of bounds " << endl;
     //Position not valid

    else
    {
        prev->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = curr;
        cout << "Node added at position: " << pos << endl;
    }
 }
 else
 {
    head = newNode;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    cout << "Added at head as list is empty! " << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* InsertNth(int data, int position)
{
  struct Node *n=new struct Node;
  n->data=data;  
  if(position==0)
  {// this will also cover insertion at head (if there is no problem with the input)

      n->next=head;
      head=n;
  }

  else
  {
      struct Node *c=new struct Node;
      int count=1;
      c=head;
      while(count!=position)
      {
          c=c->next;
          count++;
      }
      n->next=c->next;
      c->next=n;

  }
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* insert_node_at_nth_pos(Node *head, int data, int position)
{   
    /* current node */
    Node* cur = head;

    /* initialize new node to be inserted at given position */
    Node* nth = new Node;
    nth->data = data;
    nth->next = NULL;

    if(position == 0){
        /* insert new node at head */
        head = nth;
        head->next = cur;
        return head;
    }else{
        /* traverse list */
        int count = 0;            
        Node* pre = new Node;

        while(count != position){
            if(count == (position - 1)){
                pre = cur;
            }
            cur = cur->next;            
            count++;
        }

        /* insert new node here */
        pre->next = nth;
        nth->next = cur;

        return head;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For inserting at a particular position `k`, you need to traverse the list till the position `k-1` and then do the insert.

[You need not create a new node to traverse to that position as you did in your code] You should traverse from the head node.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the insertion process just like you, so here is the code how I have solved the problem:

```
void add_by_position(int data, int pos)
  {
        link *node = new link;
        link *linker = head;

        node->data = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
            linker = linker->next;
        }
        node->next = linker;
        linker = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++){
            linker = linker->next;
        }
        linker->next = node;
        boundaries++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void addToSpecific()
 {
 int n;   
 int f=0;   //flag
 Node *temp=H;    //H-Head, T-Tail
 if(NULL!=H)  
 {
    cout<<"Enter the Number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    while(NULL!=(temp->getNext()))
    {
       if(n==(temp->getInfo()))
       {
      f=1;
      break;
       }
       temp=temp->getNext();
    }
 }
 if(NULL==H)
 {
    Node *nn=new Node();
    nn->setInfo();
    nn->setNext(NULL);
    T=H=nn;
 }
 else if(0==f)
 {
    Node *nn=new Node();
    nn->setInfo();
    nn->setNext(NULL);
    T->setNext(nn);
    T=nn;
 }
 else if(1==f)
 {
    Node *nn=new Node();
    nn->setInfo();
    nn->setNext(NULL);
    nn->setNext((temp->getNext()));
    temp->setNext(nn);
 }
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

**structure of node object:**

```
class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int);
    ~Node();
    void setData(int);
    int getData();
    void setNext(Node*);
    Node* getNext();
};
```

**Implementation of the function:**

Returning a status value is always a god practice, constants defined here are meant for debugging/logging the application usage.

```
//constants
static int const SUCCESS = 0;
static int const FAILURE = 1;
static int const NULL_OBJ = 2;
static int const POS_EXCEED = 3;

int addAt(int data, int pos){
    Node *tmp = new Node(data);
    if (tmp == NULL){
        //print for debugging only.
        cout << "Object not created. Out of memory maybe" << endl;
        return NULL_OBJ;
    }
    if (pos == 0){
        // add at beginning
        tmp->setNext(this->head);
        this->head = tmp;
        return SUCCESS;
    }else{
        // add element in between or at end
        int counter = 1;
        Node* currentNode = this->head;
        while (counter < pos && currentNode->getNext() != NULL){
            currentNode= currentNode->getNext();
            counter++;
       }
       tmp->setNext(currentNode->getNext());
       currentNode->setNext(tmp);
       return SUCCESS;
   }
   cout << "Failed due to unknown reason.";
   return FAILURE;
}
```

Assumption here is that, you will call the function after validating the inputs (data and position). Though we can validate the parameters inside the function, it is not a good practice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Insert an element at very beginning position.
case-1 when the list is empty.
case-2 When the list is not empty.

```
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
int data;
Node* next; //link == head =stored the address of the next node
};

Node* head;  //pointer to Head node with empty list

void Insert(int y);
void print();

int main(){
    head = nullptr; //empty list
    int n,y;
    cout<<"how many number do you want to enter?"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Enter the number "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>y;
        Insert(y);
        print();
    }
}

void Insert(int y){
    Node* temp = new Node(); //create dynamic memory allocation
    temp->data = y;
    temp->next = head; // temp->next = null; when list is empty
    head = temp;
}

void print(){
    Node* temp = head;
    cout<<"List is: "<<endl;
    while(temp!= nullptr){
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code Fixed**

/* Insert node at a given position in a linked list.
The first element in the linked list is at position 0
*/

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node
{
   int data;
   struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *head;

void Insert(int data, int n)
{
   Node* temp1 = new Node();
   temp1->data = data;
   temp1->next = NULL;
   if (n == 1){
    temp1->next = head;
    head = temp1;
    return;
   }
   Node* temp2 = head ;  //Here Only You need to assign what in head to 
                         //Pointer Variable temp2 and traverse
   for (int i = 0; i < n-2; i++){
    temp2 = temp2->next;
   }
   temp1->next = temp2->next;
   temp2->next = temp1;        // linking Whats in Temp1 To Temp2 (next)
}
void print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    head = NULL; //empty linked list
    Insert(7,1); //List: 7     
    Insert(5,2); //List: 7,5   
    Insert(8,3); //List: 7,5,8 
    Insert(6,1); //List: 6,7,5,8   
    Insert(10,3);//List: 6,7,10,5,8 
    print();
system("pause");
}
```